# python+ray: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)

Tags: python

This problem occurred when I tried to reproduce the code. The following is the relevant information of the code and the error information.

## **System information:**

OS Platform and Distribution:Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Ray installed from (source or binary): source
Ray version:0.4.0
Python version: 3.6.10
Code used:https://github.com/ninalopatina/Rocket_RL

## **python Rocket_RL/python/main.py**

```
`from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
 Import the Rocket_RL functions
import Rocket_RL.python.func.data_processing as RocketData
import Rocket_RL.python.func.ray_funcs as RF
import argparse, os, yaml
import ray
from ray.tune import run_experiments
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-rreg','--run_reg', dest = 'run_regression', type = bool,
                        default = True, help = 'True to run the regression')
    parser.add_argument('-sreg','--save_reg', dest = 'save_regression', type = bool,
                        default = False, help = 'True to save the regression')
    parser.add_argument('-rRL','--run_RL', dest = 'run_RL', type = bool,
                        default = True, help = 'True to run RL model')
    parser.add_argument('-pRL','--plot_RL', dest = 'plot_RL', type = bool,
                        default = True, help = 'True to plot RL results')
    parser.add_argument('-plot','--plot_data', dest = 'plot_data', type = int,
                        default = False, help = 'True to plot Fluent simulation data in 3d')
    parser.add_argument('-cfg','--config', dest = 'config_dir', type = str,
                        default = 'Rocket_RL/config/config.yml', help = 'where the config file is located')
    parser.add_argument('-rayinit','--rayinit', dest = 'rayinit', type = bool,
                        default = True, help = 'should only be init the first time you run if running in an IDE')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
    config_path = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,args.config_dir)
    with open(config_path, 'r') as ymlfile:
        cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)
    cfg['CWD_PATH'] = CWD_PATH
    # If importing new data, set plot_data to true to take a glance at it to verify
    # if it looks reasonable.
    if (args.plot_data==True) | (args.run_regression == True):
        RocketData.data_process(cfg,args.plot_data,args.run_regression,args.save_regression)
    if args.run_RL == True:
        if args.rayinit == True:
            ray.init()
        run_experiments({
            "RocketRL": {
                "run": cfg['agent'],# Which agent to run
                #conditions under which you would stop:
                "stop": {"time_total_s": cfg['time_total_s'], "timesteps_total": cfg['timesteps_total'], "episode_reward_mean": cfg['episode_reward_mean']},
                #The custom environment:
                "env": "AllVar-v0",
                #Checkpoint on every iteration:
                "checkpoint-freq":1,
                #Num workers has to be 1 fewer than the available CPU!!!!!
                "config": {
                    "num_workers": 0,
                    "gamma": cfg['gamma'],
                    "horizon": cfg['horizon'],
                    "num_sgd_iter": cfg['num_sgd_iter'],
                    "sgd_stepsize": cfg['sgd_stepsize'],
                    "timesteps_per_batch": cfg['timesteps_per_batch'],
                    "min_steps_per_task": cfg['min_steps_per_task']
                },
            },
        })
    if args.plot_RL == True:
        df_model = RF.rllib_plot(cfg)`
```

## **Describe the problem**

```
Error processing event: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trial_runner.py", line 218, in _process_events
    result = ray.get(result_id)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 2321, in get
    raise RayGetError(object_ids, value)
ray.worker.RayGetError: Could not get objectid ObjectID(77a11678718aa275b17c7236613bb1ede7cc3bdf). It was created by remote function train which failed with:

Remote function train failed with:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 821, in _process_task
    *arguments)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/actor.py", line 212, in actor_method_executor
    method_returns = method(actor, *args)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trainable.py", line 109, in train
    result = self._train()
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/rllib/ppo/ppo.py", line 134, in _train
    samples = collect_samples(agents, config, self.local_evaluator)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/rllib/ppo/rollout.py", line 25, in collect_samples
    [fut_sample], _ = ray.wait(list(agent_dict))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)


Remote function train failed with:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 821, in _process_task
    *arguments)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/actor.py", line 212, in actor_method_executor
    method_returns = method(actor, *args)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/trainable.py", line 109, in train
    result = self._train()
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/rllib/ppo/ppo.py", line 134, in _train
    samples = collect_samples(agents, config, self.local_evaluator)
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/rllib/ppo/rollout.py", line 25, in collect_samples
    [fut_sample], _ = ray.wait(list(agent_dict))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)


  You can inspect errors by running

      ray.error_info()

  If this driver is hanging, start a new one with

      ray.init(redis_address="127.0.0.1:64505")
  
Worker ip unknown, skipping log sync for /home/lzy/ray_results/RocketRL/PPO_AllVar-v0_0_2023-08-08_15-03-09qvfbkn_b
== Status ==
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources used: 0/1 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs
Result logdir: /home/lzy/ray_results/RocketRL
ERROR trials:
 - PPO_AllVar-v0_0: ERROR, 1 failures: /home/lzy/ray_results/RocketRL/PPO_AllVar-v0_0_2023-08-08_15-03-09qvfbkn_b/error_2023-08-08_15-03-17.txt

== Status ==
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources used: 0/1 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs
Result logdir: /home/lzy/ray_results/RocketRL
ERROR trials:
 - PPO_AllVar-v0_0: ERROR, 1 failures: /home/lzy/ray_results/RocketRL/PPO_AllVar-v0_0_2023-08-08_15-03-09qvfbkn_b/error_2023-08-08_15-03-17.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Rocket_RL/python/main.py", line 90, in <module>
    "min_steps_per_task": cfg['min_steps_per_task']
  File "/home/lzy/miniconda3/envs/RocketEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 91, in run_experiments
    raise TuneError("Trial did not complete", trial)
ray.tune.error.TuneError: ('Trial did not complete', PPO_AllVar-v0_0)
```

I got the error, but I don't understand.It seems that the number of variables and elements does not match, but I have tried various methods but can not solve it.Please tell me if someone can teach me.I would appreciate it if you could provide me with some solutions or improvements regarding this error.

Comment: If you are seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?"), please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful  to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).